# nombre web funciona pero IP no

Tags: html, web, dns, ip, ping

quiero entrar a una pagina web, y parece que esta caida, pero si hago ping, funciona el ping sin problemas, pero si hago nslookup y hago una busqueda inversa la IP de la web no funciona, parece que no hay ningun dominio asociado a la IP, es normal? alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias a gustavo gomez, con la herramienta que me ha dicho, ya funciona todo bien, me sale:"Common Name: sni.cloudflaressl.com

Issuer: Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3" Ahora mi pregunta es, si se asocia otro nombre es decir una pagina web distinta a este dominio, saldra en los resultados? Es decir, si a esta web le cambian el nombre, con el IP de la web, puede salir el nuevo nombre?

P.S: Quiza no me he explicado bien, me ha sorprendido mucho ver que no podía hacer el nslookup, porque si podía hacer el ping, también tenia que poder hacer nslookup. Ahora que veo que se puede hacer el nslookup, **mi pregunta** es: "si puedo encontrar otras webs asociadas a la IP del dominio"

Comment: Es decir, pongo el nombre de la web i el ping funciona, pongo la ip y el nslookup no funciona

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
En vez de añadir comentarios, ten presente que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras pa añadir info. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Así pues, por favor, edit tu pregunta y dinos paso a paso qué comandos usas, qué sale y qué debería salir. ;)

Comment: Cloudflare "oculta" la ip del servidor porque actua como [proxy inverso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_inverso). Si intentas ver la IP asociada al dominio solo verás la IP del proxy de Cloudflare. Esto significa que tampoco puedes hallar otros dominios asociados a la misma IP.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Intenta con esta herramienta: https://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: los registros MX se usan para mail. E igual, qué puede hacer OP con la info que entrega esto? Y para los que revisen en el futuro la pregunta, si el sitio ya no existe, qué podrían hacer? :)